# Download corrompido com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Criei um server com o *ExpressJS* onde faço o upload e download de arquivos diversos:

```
FileController.prototype.downloadFile = function(req, res) {
      var filePath = "./upload/" + req.body.pasta + '/' + req.body.file;
      res.download(filePath, function(err){
      });
}
```

Pelo postman o download funciona perfeitamente, entretanto, pelo meu sistema o arquivo fica corrompido.

```
$scope.downloadFileWeb = function() {
  var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: webServiceControl.serverAccessInfo.host + 'download',
    headers:
     { 'x-access-token': webServiceControl.accessToken,
       'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    form:
     { pasta: $scope.manualSelecionado.idFS,
       file: $scope.arquivoSelecionado } };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error)  {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error(error)
    } else {
      var path = './media/' + $scope.arquivoSelecionado;

      fs.writeFileSync(path, body, function(error) {
           if (error) {
             console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
           } else {
             console.log("Successful Write to " + path);
           }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Defina 'corrompido'.

Comment: O arquivo não abre, visualizando por um editor de texto, percebe-se que que há dados (utilizando uma imagem como exemplo).

Comment: Os dois arquivos (o original e o recebido pelo servidor) possuem o mesmo tamanho? Já os abriu em uma ferramenta de comparação binária, como o vbindiff? Isso pode lhe dar uma dica a respeito da causa. Poste os resultados aqui, assim será mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: O servidor ainda está rodando local, portanto, em sua origem o arquivo está perfeito e abrindo normalmente, entretanto, o download vem corrompido. Testei com todos os tipos de arquivos e dá no mesmo. Fazendo a comparação binária, apenas fica explícito que não está sendo gravado corretamente. Acredito que seja a forma com que eu estou escrevendo esses arquivos, devido ao fato de funcionar perfeitamente pelo postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, o problema era a forma com que eu estava gravando o arquivo, conforme abaixo:

```
  $scope.downloadFileWeb = function() {
      var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: webServiceControl.serverAccessInfo.host + 'download',
        headers:
         { 'x-access-token': webServiceControl.accessToken,
           'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        form:
         { pasta: $scope.manualSelecionado.idFS,
           file: $scope.arquivoSelecionado } };;

      var path = './media/' + $scope.arquivoSelecionado;
      var r = request(options);

      r.on('response',  function (res) {
        res.pipe( fs.createWriteStream( path ));
      });
    }
```

Grato pela Atenção!